# Unexpected query run time results with Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, left-join

I've run into an interesting issue which I can't really understand. Essentially, I'm working with some Oracle tables and have to modify some view creation statement, specifically an exists statement in the where clause. This involved modifying slightly QUERY A in the exists clause by joining it with another table and changing the where clause of QUERY A. I figured there were 2 ways to go about it:

1. Union a new query based on QUERY A, with the additional join and the different where clause or
2. Modify QUERY A with a Left outer join (so old joins left outer join new table), and then add an or to the where clause (so old condition or new condition).

Here's a mock up of the code:

```
select count(*)
from table a
where condition and exists (
    select *
    from table1 join table2 on cond
        join table3 on cond
        join table4 on cond
    where cond
    union all
    select *
    from table1 join table2 on cond
        join table3 on cond
        join table4 on cond
        join table5 on cond
    where cond2);
```

vs.

```
select count(*)
from table a
where condition and exists (
    select *
    from table1 join table2 on cond
        join table3 on cond
        join table4 on cond
        left outer join table5 on cond
    where cond or cond2);
```

So I expected the second version to run faster since it isn't doing the first 3 joins twice; however, it turns out that version 2 has taken forever to run, while version 1 was relatively fast. Why would I see these types of results? Does it have to do with bad logic that the 2 are equivalent? Or is Oracle query optimizer handling them differently under the hood? Or could it have something to do with indexing? There's not really anything that needs to be solved here, but I would like to understand why the results turned out this way. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated, but `count(1)` is a useless optimization; the Oracle CBO rewrites your statement into `count(*)` anyway.

Comment: Huh, I wasn't aware of that, but it's neat to know. Thanks

Comment: Get execution plans for both selects, post both plans here, and I'll explain the differences to you.

Comment: I wish I could, but unfortunately I don't have the access necessary for the system to do so. I'm going to assume that this issue could be due to indexing? Though that still seems strange to me as the 2 queries use the same columns.

Comment: You can't tell without execution plans.